# Set return type of function to array with multiple indices

Tags: javascript, mujs

I need to be able to return an array with 6 indices.

```js
natives.on("render", function () {
    const [year, month, day, hour, minute, second] = getLocalTime();
});
```

```cpp
js_newarray(js);
{
    ?
    ?
    ...
}
```

Comment: I've added some information regarding the usage of the js_newarray function. I've tried pushnumber, setindex, to no avail. I am still in the search for a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

Took a bit of work, but I managed to figure out a solution to this problem.

```cpp
    js_newarray(js);
    {
        // You could have an incrementing idx here.
        js_pushnumber(js, year);
        js_setindex(js, -2, 0);

        js_pushnumber(js, month);
        js_setindex(js, -2, 1);

        js_pushnumber(js, day);
        js_setindex(js, -2, 2);

        js_pushnumber(js, hour);
        js_setindex(js, -2, 3);

        js_pushnumber(js, minute);
        js_setindex(js, -2, 4);

        js_pushnumber(js, second);
        js_setindex(js, -2, 5);
    }
```

```js
// Must be transpiled from typescript to ES5 javascript.
natives.on("render", () => {
    const [year, month, day, hour, minute, second] = getLocalTime();
    DRAW_TEXT(`Y: ${year} | M: ${month} | D: ${day} | H: ${hour} | M: ${minute} | S: ${second}`, 7, {x: 0.0, y: 0.0}, 1.0, {red: 255, blue: 0, green: 0, alpha: 255}, true, true, true);
});
```